# Spring boot spring EL in yml configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to conditionally substitute value if some environment variable is set.

For example

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include:
    - 'base'
    - 'FOO' (only if `FOO` is set to true in env variable)
```

Comment: then why don't you pass `FOO` as active profile?

Comment: @Deadpool I want to control the inclusion of configurations via `application.yml`

Answer (score 0):

YAML doesn't have conditional logic in it, but if you're willing to put the value in the environment variable - you can do this:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: ${MY_FOO_ENV:base}
```

Set your MY_FOO_ENV to 'FOO'. The ':base' sets a default value if MY_FOO_ENV is not defined in the environment.

Comment: Let me clarify the question. I want `base` in the list regardless, I want to add `FOO` to the list only if `FOO` is set in environment variable

Comment: So set your env variable to 'base,FOO'

Comment: Syntax of list is different in YAML it is not comma delimited values.

Comment: Some days I'm useful - others not so much. =/

Comment: You could also switch to a .properties file - then comma separated works great.

Comment: properties is not an option for now, Thanks for your efforts Kieveli.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on documention: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

As documentation says: you can set dinamically so you will have to create some component before application runs, on this component you will have to verify if some variable of environment exists with that key.  You can use  @Value("${FOO}") String foo; so in that component verify if foo is different to null then setProfiles.